# TestFlight - How to submit for Beta App Review

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm new to TestFlight. I'm setting up beta testing of my new App for external testers. I'm following various guides such as [this](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/devdc42b26b8). I've uploaded a build and set up external testers. When trying to select a build for testing I'm warned "before your build can be tested, it may have to be approved by Beta App Review".

Fair enough.

When I select the "Next" button a spinning wheel appears and nothing ever seems to happen again. Attached is a screenshot (the screen background is greyed out but you can read it). I've waited, and waited, and waited.....

[image]

Refreshing the browser doesn't help. There is no feedback from iTunes connect. Shall I just stare at my screen for 1 to 2 days hoping eventually the beta review will happen and the spinning wheel will stop? I think not.

So my question - how do I submit a build for Beta App Review? I see no button anywhere or explanation of the process.

Comment: Did you manage to figure out what the issue was? I am still struggling with this and contacted them but not response. :(

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't worked it out. I've been forced to only do beta testing with internal testers. I'd hoped the recent iTunes Connect upgrade would fix this but haven't tried this again since the upgrade and don't have time in the next couple of weeks to revisit this. If Apple responds to you or you do work out how to get it working please let us know.

Comment: OK, so something strange happened, I tried the same thing in the morning today and it managed to work. Didn't change anything just submitted it again.

You might want to retry and see? Really strange issue though :(

Comment: Where did you even find the 'next' button?  What I don't understand is how to actually request a beta app review in the first place.  It is far from obvious.  Underneath the build it says "Waiting for app review" but no where does it indicate how to kick that review off.

Answer (score 16):

I had this problem and worked around it by adding the build to a tester group (under that groups tab) instead of adding testers, or a group of testers to the build.

Comment: As odd as this advice sounds, it has allowed me to submit the app for Beta App Review. Other techniques did not help. I tried submitting the app for normal review and this did not clear things up even though it was approved.  Luckily, I configured it to be manually released. I was this close to trying to get it published in order to start the TestFlight process. Cheers!

Comment: Adding the build to the tester group does it. The steps to do it are a bit obscure. On left of screen, select a beta Group. Click Builds tab. (Hard to see... until you do.) Click the big round plus sign, and select a new build. This triggers the "Submit for Beta Approval" flow.

Answer (score 4):

You're doing it correctly. It's just a matter of adding external testers to the build and clicking that "Next" button. Try a different browser.

Comment: The problem appears in several browsers.

Comment: What 'Next' button?  I cannot find a Next button anywhere.  The only button I see is 'Expire Build'.

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same issue as well. It looks like Apple has broke somthing when updating iTunes Connect. If you open the developer tools in google chrome and bring up Console you get the below error: [image: Showing Error]

And before anyone says anything the Feedback Email section on testflight information is a correct Email address.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this problem; my app accesses HealthKit, and I had to provide a privacy policy URL in the 'Test Information' section (available in the sidebar). I had previously added the privacy policy URL on the main description page, but I would just see the spinner when I hit 'Submit for Review' (for TestFlight) until I added the URL to the 'Test Information' section.